# How to display dropdown fields based on column count and manage state individually for each dropdwon in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on front-end part of application using react and material-ui. So i have a requirement of displaying the drop-down boxes with some data types as options values. And manage that state in useState hook for every individual drop-down.

I tried something like this,

```
<TableRow>
          {
            Object.keys(filteredData[0]).map(field => {
              console.log('field', field);
              return (
                 <> 
                   <TableCell align="left" key={field} className={classes.headings}>
                     <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <FormControl className={classes.margin}>
                            <NativeSelect
                              id="demo-customized-select-native"
                              input={<BootstrapInput />}
                              value={type}
                              onChange={handleChange}
                            > 
                              <option value={10}>Type</option>
                              <option value={20}>string</option>
                              <option value={30}>interger</option>
                              <option value={40}>float</option>
                           </NativeSelect>
                        </FormControl>
                    </div>
                  </TableCell>
                 </>
              ) 
              }
            )}
      </TableRow>
```

Assume, The fileteredData is a array having some objects that are coming from database (object are treated as columns count). So successfully displayed the dropdown based the count of array objects.

Now my problem is, Whenever i change the value using dropdown, it changes every other dropdown value, That's because, I'm using same state value in Onchange event provided by react.

Here is my state and onChange()

```
  const [type, setType] = React.useState('');  

  const handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event)
    setType(event.target.value);
  };
```

I want to store each value in state object, And send that object as payload to another api call..

How to tackle this kind of problem.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thats because you have a single state i.e clicked for all of the `selectboxes`, this will trigger for all `selectboxes`

There are two solutions for this kind of problem.

1. create a wrapper component for your `NativeSelect` component and move the state and onChange function in that component.
2. If you dont want to move your state into any inner component you need to declare a new variable in the state for every corresponding `selectBox` element and also change the logic `handleChange` accordingly. 
   Or you can have an id in your state and pass the onChange function with an id i.e.

```js
onChange = { index => 
    //Possibly the index coming from the map function
            (index) =>handleChange(index, value);
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, some work around with id's from map function and its works. :)